# Can not get grade in API JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

I had data results to API :

```json
"tabledata": [
  {
    "itemname": {
      "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 b1b b1t column-itemname",
      "colspan": 7,
      "content": "<i class=\"icon fa fa-folder fa-fw icon itemicon\"  title=\"Category\" aria-label=\"Category\"></i>Intro to Computing IT1016",
      "celltype": "th",
      "id": "cat_2_23"
    },
  },
  {
    "itemname": {
      "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b column-itemname",
      "colspan": 1,
      "content": "<a title=\"Link to Quiz activity Exercise 2.1\" class=\"gradeitemheader\" ><img class=\"icon itemicon\"  alt=\"Quiz\" />Exercise 2.1</a>",
      "celltype": "th",
      "id": "row_94_23"
    },
                    
    "grade": {
      "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-grade",
      "content": "10.00",
      "headers": "cat_2_23 row_94_23 grade"
    },
  },
]
```

I could get itemname.content but grade.content can not.

How can I code get grade.content and substring itemname.content?

I code javascript and react

Comment: Can you update your question to show us what the code you are using is doing? We can't really help if we can't see what the code is doing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you can get `itemname.content` you should be able to use the same method to get `grade.content`.

Answer (score 0):

In json api the points are not put, the get is done directly with /itemname

Answer (score 0):

if you added a blank grade to the first object it would probably find it.

```
[
{
  itemname: {},
  grade: {},
}
]
```

you want your base level object structure to be consistent within the array so you're not having to check undefined all the time.

Comment: so parsing would be tabledata.filter(item => item.grade)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear yet exactly what you are doing to access the fields I'll assume you are simply trying to map the data and hitting null/undefined access errors when an element hasn't the `grade` property. As you are iterating over the array you can use the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to prevent accidental null/undefined accesses.

```
el.itemname?.content
el.grade?.content
```

> Optional Chaining
>
> The **optional chaining** operator (`?.`) enables you to read the
> value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects
> without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.
>
> The `?.` operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that
> instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or
> `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of
> undefined. When used with function calls, it returns `undefined` if
> the given function does not exist.

```js
const tabledata = [
  {
    "itemname": {
      "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 b1b b1t column-itemname",
      "colspan": 7,
      "content": "<i class=\"icon fa fa-folder fa-fw icon itemicon\"  title=\"Category\" aria-label=\"Category\"></i>Intro to Computing IT1016",
      "celltype": "th",
      "id": "cat_2_23"
    },
  },
  {
    "itemname": {
      "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b column-itemname",
      "colspan": 1,
      "content": "<a title=\"Link to Quiz activity Exercise 2.1\" class=\"gradeitemheader\" ><img class=\"icon itemicon\"  alt=\"Quiz\" />Exercise 2.1</a>",
      "celltype": "th",
      "id": "row_94_23"
    },
    "grade": {
      "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-grade",
      "content": "10.00",
      "headers": "cat_2_23 row_94_23 grade"
    },
  },
];

tabledata.forEach(el => {
  console.log("item:", el.itemname?.content);
  console.log("grade:", el.grade?.content);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! keyword : Optional Chaining. But I want to substring itemname.content, you can suggestions to me take Intro to Computing IT1016 and  Exercise 2.1. My big brother <3

Comment: @TedMinh Are these substring values dynamic? Is there a pattern/structure to the `itemname.content` values that you can depend on?

Comment: `"first value":"<i class=\"icon fa fa-folder fa-fw icon itemicon\"  title=\"Category\" aria-label=\"Category\"></i>Intro to Computing IT1016"`
`"second value": "<a title=\"Link to Quiz activity Exercise 2.1\" class=\"gradeitemheader\" href=\""><img class=\"icon itemicon\" src=\" alt=\"Quiz\" />Exercise 2.1</a>","`
`"third value":"<a title=\"Link to Quiz activity Exercise 2.2\" class=\"gradeitemheader\" href=\""><img class=\"icon itemicon\" src=\"" alt=\"Quiz\" />Exercise 2.2</a>","`
I have no idea for this.

Comment: @TedMinh I guess you do string searches for the end of the `i` tag to grab the first string, and could probably use a regex for grabbing the "Exercise n.n" strings. Is it possible to get the data not already as formatted HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Do itemname and grade have to be in the same object?

If not you could do the following...

```
"tabledata": [
  {
    "itemname": {
      "class": "level1 levelodd oddd1 b1b b1t column-itemname",
      "colspan": 7,
      "content": "<i class=\"icon fa fa-folder fa-fw icon itemicon\"  title=\"Category\" aria-label=\"Category\"></i>Intro to Computing IT1016",
      "celltype": "th",
      "id": "cat_2_23"
    },
  },
  {
    "itemname": {
      "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b column-itemname",
      "colspan": 1,
      "content": "<a title=\"Link to Quiz activity Exercise 2.1\" class=\"gradeitemheader\" ><img class=\"icon itemicon\"  alt=\"Quiz\" />Exercise 2.1</a>",
      "celltype": "th",
      "id": "row_94_23"
    },
  },
  {           
    "grade": {
      "class": "level2 leveleven item b1b itemcenter  column-grade",
      "content": "10.00",
      "headers": "cat_2_23 row_94_23 grade"
    },
  },
]
```